# How to concatinate string with date in Dataflow expression builder

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Why this does not work in dataflow expression builder in azure data factory:
concat(subDays(currentUTC(),-1),'.parquet')

I dont understand why is it so difficult???

Comment: can you provide what is your expected result from the above expression?

Comment: You don't need concat. Just cast to string and use + like this: toString(subDays(currentUTC(),-1))+'.parquet'

Answer (score 1):

**Concat** function expects its arguments to be of 'string' type. But subDays(currentUTC(),1) will give the data in **timestamp** / **date** type. This is the reason we get the error as `Type mismatch`

[image]

In order to remove this error message, convert the timestamp data to string type using `toString()`. The expression will be,

`concat(toString(subDays(currentUTC(),-1)),'.parquet')`

[image]

**Result:**
This expression gives result without any error. This expression subtract `-1` from **currentUTC()** day. Subtracting -1 is nothing but adding one to the day.

[image]